# How to interpolate two different strings into the same template conditionally?

Tags: angular, string-interpolation

I am new to Angular and I can't find a solution for the following scenario: I have the following navigation, where `register as a family` and `register as a sitter` links to the same component template, e.g `register`.

My question is that how can I dynamically customise the `register template` for instance with interpolation so that when I am at `register as a family` it displays a title such`register as a family` and vice versa.

Or am I using the wrong approach ?

This is navbar.component.html :

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <div class="navigation">
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menuSitter">For sitters
    </button>
    <mat-menu class="example-menu" #menuSitter="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item routerLink="find-family" routerLinkActive="active">
        <span>Find a familiy</span>
      </button>
      <button *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn" mat-menu-item routerLink="register" routerLinkActive="active">
        <span>Register as a sitter</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menuFamily">For host families
    </button>
    <mat-menu class="example-menu" #menuFamily="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item routerLink="find-sitter" routerLinkActive="active">
        <span>Find a sitter</span>
      </button>
      <button *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn" mat-menu-item routerLink="register" routerLinkActive="active">
        <!--(click)="showSignupForm()"-->
        <span>Register as a family</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>
```

This is register.component.html:

```
 <h2 class="mat-title" style="text-align:center;">Register as a {{person}}</h2>
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="registerForm" (submit)="onSubmit(registerForm)" novalidate>
 /* code */
</form>
```

Shortly how can I conditionally change the value of `{{person}}` in `register.componet.ts` ?

Comment: Can you not add a paremeter in your routing? `path: '/register/:registrationType'`

Comment: and how can I extract the value from the parameter ?

Comment: See answer for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your routing to include a parameter indicating the type of registration

```
//routing.ts
//Add this route
{path: '/register/:registrationType', component: RegistrationComponent }
```

Inject the route in your component and initialise person variable based on the registration type

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

person: string;
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      let registrationType = params['registrationType'];
      this.person = registrationType == 'person' : 'Person' : 'Family'
    });
```

Modify your router links

```
 <button *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn" mat-menu-item routerLink="register/person" routerLinkActive="active">
    <span>Register as a sitter</span>
  </button>


  <button *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn" mat-menu-item routerLink="register/family" routerLinkActive="active">
    <!--(click)="showSignupForm()"-->
    <span>Register as a family</span>
  </button>
```

Comment: You will have both buttons displayed with this approach, look on `ngIf`s.

Comment: OP wants To change displayed value in register component, he does not indicate that he only wants one button in the navbar

Comment: It doesn't like the following line:   `this.person = registrationType == 'person' : 'Person' : 'Family';` - throws this error: `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: P.S: I fixed it by only using `this.person = registrationType;` which makes sense since registrationType it holds the param values. Can I ask you why you did it that way ?

Comment: It was so that you could have a url friendly registration type (e.g. `person` 
 - lowercase, no space) and a matching user friendly person description (Person, or Baby Sitter). I wrote it quickly and forgot the brackets I guess. Should have been : `this.person = (registrationType == 'person' ? 'Person' : 'Family')`